# Wordpress top navigation menu links inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a theme called Ironbull and when wordpress generates a menu the custom links are inactive. They are shown and when I hover the links the URL shows, but it wont load the link or open a new window.

There are a few "scroll to ID" links which works on the frontpage, but thats it. If I right-click on the link and press open in new window it loads.

I'm working on this site localy so please tell me if you need me to post any part of the code.

Many thanks

Comment: Well.. of course we need some code... If we were some kind of saige, we wouldn't be programming, instead we should be stealing people's money with our 'guessing' abilities  :D

Comment: I understand, the problem is I wouldn't know what part of the code might be messing with this. Any guess?